# How to reference jsse classes in Android?

Tags: android, encryption, jsse

I am using Eclipse Helios with Android SDK plugin and writing for Android 2.2

I am attempting to write an app the encrypts communication that is sent to a web service, but errors

It fails at

```
    // wrap with RSA public key
    ObjectInputStream keyIn = new ObjectInputStream(getResource(getFileLocation(PUBLIC_KEY, localTest)));
    Key publicKey = (Key) keyIn.readObject();
    keyIn.close();
```

with error in console...

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.JSA_RSAPublicKey

which is a class in the jsse.jar file.  If I attempt to include the jsse.jar file in the build path, I get a warning error and complaining by the compiler.

" trouble processing "javax/net/ServerSocketFactory.class":"

How does one reference this library or reference the core android's library correctly?

FYI, this works ok as a Java app but not in the Android module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok as soon as I posted my last comment, I realized the issue might be in the JRE that developed the keys.  Thus, I had to recreate the keys using JRE 1.5 because the Android system is using at least JRE 1.5.  That seems to have worked!

Answer (score 1):

A lot of Android's libraries are custom versions of already existing ones, also javax is meant more for servers.

Try looking at encryption API's such as [BouncyCastles](http://bouncycastle.org).

If you're using an older version of Android, there is already a bit of bouncycastle in there but for newer versions like the one you're using, I'd recommend importing one of theirs.

Comment: I am using a BouncyCastle library in the build path. I have put the 1.6 version and tried the 1.4 version without success.  I have the jdk1.6 library included in the classpath (which has a jsse.jar file). The class is specific to the 1.4.2 Java runtime. If I include that in the buildpath it still doesnt work.